# "Sort" command using ascii order

Tags: shell, sort

I would like to use `sort` to sort by ASCII value, or at least by not disregarding punctuation, i.e:

```
sort <<DATA
a.01
a.04
a2
a.3
a.2
DATA
```

Should produce

```
a.01
a.04
a.2
a.3
a2
```

Especially these properties are important:

- Dots are not ignored, so `a.2 < a.3 < a2`
- Numbers are not treated specially, so `a.04 < a.3`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: In case it's not clear, `LC_COLLATE=C sort …` should do what you want.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment stating otherwise, and for disregarding the prompt for the existing solution, it totally solves the problem.

Comment: blah, even though it has exactly the right answer, that linked question was one of the worst _questions_ I've seen in a while...